# Angular - *ngIf is only checking after click for native element

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to create a card collection that should be able to be scrolled from left to right with buttons. If the container with cards in it is too big, a button should appear and if I click the button, then a button for scrolling to the left should appear and the container should be scrolled. The issue now is that it seems like `*ngIf` is only checking after I click on another element.

The container looks something like that (this should be a playlist):

[image: screenshot]

I thought about maybe the element needs to be re-focused, so JavaScript knows "Hey, it seems like my scrollLeft changed", but that did not work.

I have these two buttons:

```
<button *ngIf="showLeftScroll()" mat-icon-button class="scroll-button-left" (click)="scrollLeft()"><mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon></button>
<button *ngIf="isScrollable()" mat-icon-button class="scroll-button-right" (click)="scrollRight()"><mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon></button>
```

And the methods are:

```
isScrollable() {
  const container = this.cardContainer.nativeElement;
  const isScrollable = container.offsetWidth < container.scrollWidth;
  const isNotAtTheEnd = container.offsetWidth + container.scrollLeft !== container.scrollWidth;
  return (isScrollable && isNotAtTheEnd);
}

showLeftScroll() {
  return this.cardContainer.nativeElement.scrollLeft > 0;
}

scrollRight() {
  this.cardContainer.nativeElement.scrollLeft += 600;
  this.cardContainer.nativeElement.focus();
}

scrollLeft() {
  this.cardContainer.nativeElement.scrollLeft -= 600;
  this.cardContainer.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

---

**What happens at the moment?**

I click the button for scrolling to the right, it scrolls to the right, but the button for scrolling left only appears if I click on any other element.

**What should happen?**

The button for scrolling to the left should be shown right at the moment when I click on the button for scrolling to the right.

Comment: instead of function `showLeftScroll()` try with a variable/property

Comment: isScrollable.. That's a variable and method name. Try changing var name to scrollable and seeing if that helps.

Comment: @JGFMK good catch but that was not the issue.

Comment: @ashish pal I tried, but it did not work.

Comment: At the end of `scrollLeft()` and `scrollRight()`, try calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan thanks! Using `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` when the scrolling event happens, works! Nice!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force an immediate update of the `*ngIf` directive, call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` at the end of the scrolling methods:

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

scrollRight() {
  this.cardContainer.nativeElement.scrollLeft += 600;
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}

scrollLeft() {
  this.cardContainer.nativeElement.scrollLeft -= 600;
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```